Training RL model with TF over all the output vector
I'm training a deep RL model with TensorFlow, but my model doesn't have a single correct action. The output of the network is a vector [x1, x2], and both are actions that need to be optimized.
def train_step(self, state, reward, action):
        
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            state = tf.convert_to_tensor(state, dtype=tf.float32)
            action = tf.convert_to_tensor(action, dtype=tf.float32)
            reward = tf.convert_to_tensor(reward, dtype=tf.float32)

            predicted_action = self.actor(state, training=True)

            # Aquí calculamos el loss directamente basado en la acción real y la recompensa
            loss = -tf.reduce_mean(predicted_action * reward)
            print("LOSS:", loss)

        grads = tape.gradient(loss, self.actor.trainable_variables)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.actor.trainable_variables))


        self.epsilon = self.epsilon*self.epsilon_dec

I have my reward function defined as follows:
def transform_actions_to_reward(actions, state, agent, tipo, iteration):
    
    
    actions = actions[0]

    energy = state[0]
    price = state[1]
    battery_charge = state[2]

    percentage_stored = actions[0]
    percentage_empty = actions[1]

    energy_stored = energy*percentage_stored
    energy_iny = energy*(1-percentage_stored)

    battery_iny = agent.battery*percentage_empty

    agent.fill_bat(energy_stored)

    if price == 1:
      reward = (energy_iny + battery_iny)
    elif price == 0:
      reward = -(energy_iny + battery_iny)

    
    reward = reward

The problem is with my training function, which I got from a forum, and I haven't been able to optimize the actions correctly. I see that it's calculating the loss as the reward multiplied by the actions, but the reward corresponds to the previous actions. However, if I try to use the previous actions to calculate the loss, I get an error.
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['lstm_14/lstm_cell/kernel:0', 'lstm_14/lstm_cell/recurrent_kernel:0', 'lstm_14/lstm_cell/bias:0', 'lstm_15/lstm_cell/kernel:0', 'lstm_15/lstm_cell/recurrent_kernel:0', 'lstm_15/lstm_cell/bias:0', 'dense_7/kernel:0', 'dense_7/bias:0'],). Provided `grads_and_vars`

What should i do?

In deep reinforcement learning (RL), the training step typically involves updating the policy network (actor) based on the actions it takes and the rewards it receives. In your case, it seems you're trying to directly use the rewards to compute the loss and backpropagate through your actor network. However, there are a few issues with your current approach,You mentioned that using the previous actions to calculate the loss leads to an error about no gradients being provided. This is because the previous actions are not part of the computational graph when you calculate the gradients.

The reward function should be designed in a way that it can be used to train the network efficiently. If the rewards are calculated outside the context of the model, you need to ensure they are correctly associated with the actions taken by the model.It's often helpful to normalize rewards or use additional techniques like reward shaping to stabilize training.
